# Font in code blocks

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, fonts

Has the font in code blocks changed recently? Is this intended?

Being exclusively active in the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag, I'm very irritated by the distracting misalignment of `<` and `-`, which together are the assignment operator in R. This is how it looks like (in Firefox 117.0.1 with default settings on Windows 10 Enterprise):

[image: Screenshot showing R code]

If I change the settings in Firefox to disallow websites using their own fonts (which means the Consolas font is used), it looks much better:

[image: screenshot showing the same R code with different font setting]

Actual code block for check for rendered differences:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = x_values, y = y_actual)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()
```

Please consider using a better font in code blocks.

Comment: Firefox, Mac, this is what I see: https://cln.sh/0xL9GVYBP1ZCWPHkT3Kr

Comment: I haven't heard any news about another font change since [the change to system font in May 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/241919). FWIW, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lw6L.png) is what I see on Chrome 117, Windows 10. Did you (accidentally) install Cascadia Mono or Segoe UI Mono?

Comment: @AndrewT. It could well be related to me updating the browser. I did not install any fonts (I don't even have admin rights on the machine).

Comment: Note that you can install user fonts without admin rights on Windows 10 and 11, and programs can do so as well. You might want to check `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` and see if any fonts appeared (and possibly `%windir%\Fonts` as well, recent Office builds come with new fonts afaik and might've installed automatically).

Comment: Also note, Firefox can reveal the actual fonts used. Enter the inspector (Ctrl + I), select the code block, and in the rightmost box, select "Fonts". For me, it's still Consolas. You may want to edit in what it is for you.

Comment: @ErikA Thanks, installing LibreOffice has caused this.

Comment: The font family is specified as `ui-monospace, "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace`. So if your OS has a higher priority `ui-monospace` font, that will be rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Erik A, I found that a recent installation of LibreOffice has caused this. After deinstalling LibreOffice, I see the proper font. However, I would still say that this indicates a bug in the website. Clearly, they are using the wrong font somewhere and users only don't have issues because it isn't installed.

Comment: You do not need to uninstall LibreOffice. Just deleting the offending fonts should be enough.

Comment: @yivi I'm not starting to mess with installed fonts if I have no idea what the possible side effects are. I only needed LibreOffice for a specific task and that task is done.

Comment: And having to deinstall fonts for proper code display in a website is just absurd.

Comment: SO is deliberately designed to let the system pick the proper font for code blocks. It's not a bug, it's a feature :D